# Sort column in DataTable with same values

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have a question about sorting in Datatable. I have a table like below and want to sort it from small to big. The problem is when i have same numbers, i want to have the first as the last and so on...

Table:-----------------------------------After Sorting:

```
Name   Bit   Size                      Name    Bit     Size    (corrected)
 A      0     1                         A      0         1
 C      1     2                         C      1         2   
 B      1     3                         B      1         3
 D      1     1                         D      1         1
```

Result that i want:

```
Name    Bit   Size (corrected)
 A      0     1  
 D      1     1
 B      1     3
 C      1     2
```

My Code:

```
arraySBit.DefaultView.Sort = "Bit";
arraySBit = arraySBit.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
var tblSorted = table.AsEnumerable()
                     .OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("Bit"))
                     .CopyToDataTable();
```

**Edit**: But actually `DataView.Sort` should also work (tested).

Since you have edited your question. Your requirement seems weired. If the `Bit` is the same you don't want to order by something but you want to `reverse` the "order" of the rows of the equal rows (so the `Ordinal` position in the `DataTable`).

This does what you want although i'm not sure that it's really what you need:

```
DataTable tblSorted = table.AsEnumerable()
                 .Select((Row, Ordinal) => new {Row,Ordinal})
                 .OrderBy(x => x.Row.Field<int>("Bit"))
                 .ThenByDescending(x => x.Ordinal)
                 .Select(x => x.Row)
                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

Basically it passes the index of the row in the table via this overload [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) into an anonymous type. Then it'll sort by `Bit` first and the index/ordinal second.

Comment: where is the size sort here ? he wants first by bit , then by size

Comment: To be picky it's Linq to dataset but you get the +1 anyway ;)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Why do you assume that he wants to order by bit and size?

Comment: @Royi Namir, I think he actually wants bit and then same order as original table

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the linq query will preserve the order on same bits. @vc74: Linq-ToDataSet is not a protected term, i use `Linq-To-DataSet` primarily on (strongly typed) DataSet queries and `Linq-To-DataTable` on queries on "loos"  `DataTables`. It's just a term and actually it's a subset of `Linq-To-Objects`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Im struggling with myself - _"will this actually will save the rows  as the original order? and if yes - why the OP code didn't do that already...."_ ( even if it emits `datarow[]` , still why didn't it do it already )

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I mean, that's what MS calls it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx

Comment: @RoyiNamir i thought he wanted bit then size sort too, as is easy to see from the examples he has given! Perhaps though the data set was too small and we noticed patterns where we should not have

Comment: @RoyiNamir: i've just tested it with `DataView.Sort` and it works as expected(same as linq). If he wants to order by `Size` second he hasn't told us.

Comment: yeah ( I posted before seeing your comment)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: why do i have another result using DataView.Sort, not like yours? like sort from below to the top

Comment: @LeVietHung: Why is "1,1,3,2"  from below to the top? However, i get "1,2,3,1" with `DataView.Sort` and `Linq`, hence i asume that you have not shown all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter:  ach sorry, my question is false. What i want is "After Sorting" not "Result that i want", so "1,1,3,2" is what i want to achive, how can i do that?

Comment: i corredted my question, please see above

Comment: @LeVietHung: Then the text of your question is also wrong: "what i want is those numbers to remain in same position"

Comment: @TimSchmelter: yes, i corredted now. Could your please show me how to do it?

Comment: @LeVietHung: Edited my answer. But note that the index in a `DataTable` is arbitrary and should normally not be used for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround,

After these lines, you should have result in arrySBit as you want

```
DataTable arrySBitClone = arrySBit.Copy();
arrySBit.DefaultViewSort.Sort = "Bit";

bool different = false;
for(int i=0; i<arrySBit.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  if(arrySBit.Rows[i]["Bit"]!=arrySBitClone.Rows[i]["Bit"])
  {
    difference = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(!different)
{
  arrySBit = arrySBit.Copy(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i'm getting right your question.
why not use Select?

DataTable dt = arraySBit.Select("", "Bit, Size").CopyToDataTable();

The first parameter of the Select Method is a condition to filter, the second is an Order By, so it should work